# gantt javascript loop issues

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart

I would like to do a loop in order to put all my data in my chart. But, I don't know how to do this. I've tried something but it does not work. I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError` at the line of the loop:

```
$(".gantt").gantt({
  source: [{
    name: "Tasks",
    desc: "",

    for (var i = 0, z = tab1.length; i < z; i++) {

      values: [{
        from: "/Date(" + tab2[i].getTime() + ")/",
        to: "/Date(" + tab3[i].getTime() + ")/",
        label: tab1[i],
        customClass: "ganttRed"
      }]
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run a `for` loop in the middle of an object declaration like that. Something like this should work tho:

```
$(".gantt").gantt({
    source: [{
        name: "Tasks",
        desc: "",
        values: tab1.map(function(tab, index) {
            return {
                from: "/Date("+tab2[index].getTime()+")/",
                to: "/Date("+tab3[index].getTime()+")/",
                label: tab,
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            }
        });
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

first thank you for your fast answer, i have tried what you said and it work but not exactly how i want :[image]

What i would like is two task (Task 1, Task 2) on two different line and not on one line.
Here is the Code :

```
var tab1 = [];

tab1[0] = "Task 1";
tab1[1] = "Task 2";

var tab2 = [];

tab2[0] = new Date("2017-04-04T00:00:00");
tab2[1] = new Date("2017-04-04T12:52:00");

var tab3 = [];

tab3[0] = new Date("2017-04-04T15:00:00");
tab3[1] = new Date("2017-04-06T06:00:00");


$(function() {

    "use strict";

    $(".gantt").gantt({
        source: [{
            name: "Sprint 0",
            desc: "Analysis",
            values:  [{
                from: "/Date("+c.getTime()+")/",
                to: "/Date("+d.getTime()+")/",
                label: "Requirement Gathering",
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            },{
                from: "/Date("+a.getTime()+")/",
                to: "/Date("+e.getTime()+")/",
                label: "Scoping",
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            }]
        },{
            desc : "Tasks",
            values: tab1.map(function(tab, index) {
                return {
                    from: "/Date("+tab2[index].getTime()+")/",
                    to: "/Date("+tab3[index].getTime()+")/",
                    label: tab1,
                    customClass: "ganttRed"
                }
            })
         }],
        navigate: "scroll",
        scale: "weeks",
        maxScale: "months",
        minScale: "hours",
        itemsPerPage: 30,
        useCookie: true,
        onItemClick: function(data) {
            alert("Item clicked - show some details");
        },
        onAddClick: function(dt, rowId) {
            alert("Empty space clicked - add an item!");
        },
        onRender: function() {
            if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
                console.log("chart rendered");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".gantt").popover({
        selector: ".bar",
        title: "I'm a popover",
        content: "And I'm the content of said popover.",
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "auto right"
    });

    prettyPrint();

});
```

Thank you for your help